# Javascript : Delete file from a folder after download

Tags: javascript

I would ask if you can delete a file after you download it with javascript.
I thought of using the .remove () but with no effect.
Can someone help me?

```
downloadlink var = document.createElement ( "a");
                    d = obj.d; # D is download method before
                    downloadlink.href = d;
                    downloadlink.className = "DOWNLOAD_LINK";
                    downloadlink.download = n;
                    downloadlink.onClick = setTimeout (function () {location.reload (true);}, 30000);
                    downloadlink.innerHTML = "<p> Download document" + n + "</ p>";
                    document.getElementById ( "results"). appendChild (downloadlink);
```

How can I modify my code so that after downloading the files you delete it from the folder?

Comment: When you want to delete, Why on first place download it?

Comment: after dowload it yes.

Comment: Which `remove()`? I'm pretty sure something like that is used for removing an element instead of removing a file. You can't access the filesystem with JavaScript in a browser

Comment: Imagine this -- you go to a website, JavaScript is allowed to manipulate your file system. Boom. System32 is now deleted.

Comment: Resolved with python flask.This is the code for the interested.Resolved with this code. `@app.route('/path/<name>')
def download(name):
    file_path ="/path/"+name
    file_handle = open(file_path, 'r')
    @after_this_request
    def remove_file(response):
        os.remove("/path/"+name)
        return response
    return send_file(file_handle)`

Answer (score 0):

No.

JavaScript, running in a web page, has no access to the user's filesystem.

Even the download script you are using works by generating a regular link and letting the browser's download manager handle it.

Comment: How can I modify my code so that after downloading the files you delete it from the folder?

Comment: @Bigzli — Given that the answer to "Can I…?" is "no" you should be able to extrapolate that the answer to "How can I… the same thing?" is "You can't"